# How to fix the [OBJECT OBJECT] in ajax to view the data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How to display the data title, image and content?

here's the code:

***view.php***

```
 $id = $_REQUEST['edit_literature_id'];
        $literature = $_REQUEST['literatureID'];
        $module = $_REQUEST['edit_moduleId'];

        if (isset($id)) {
            $dataArr = array();
            $responseArr = array();

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $literature WHERE `id`='".$id."'";

            if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $data['title'] = $row['title'];
                    $data['name'] = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['name']);
                    $data['content'] = $row['content'];

                        array_push($dataArr, $data);
                    }
                    echo  json_encode($dataArr);
                }
                mysqli_free_result($result);
            } else {
                echo "No Record";
            }
        }
```

***index.php***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#btnModalUpdate', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                rowId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                moduleData = $(this).attr('data-module');
                literatureData = $(this).attr('data-literature');
                $('#edit_id').val(rowId);
                $('#edit_module').val(moduleData);
                $('#edit_literature').val(literatureData);
                $('#edit_imageId').val(rowId);
                $('#update').val('update');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../../crud/read/view.php',
                    data: $('#modalFormUpdate').serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data)
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iHsd.png)

What I'm trying to do is to get the title, image and content.
but when I'm trying to alert the data it display `[OBJECT OBJECT]`
also I tried it `alert(data.title)` but the output is undefined.

Comment: I'd suggest putting a breakpoint on alert(data) and run in the javascript debugger so you can have a look at your data object the server is returning

Answer (score 0):

try console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,4)); or alert(JSON.stringify(data,null,4));

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
let parsedJson = JSON.parse(data);
```

in success of ajax call. then try using the parsedJson variable to get your data. 
For example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#btnModalUpdate', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                rowId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                moduleData = $(this).attr('data-module');
                literatureData = $(this).attr('data-literature');
                $('#edit_id').val(rowId);
                $('#edit_module').val(moduleData);
                $('#edit_literature').val(literatureData);
                $('#edit_imageId').val(rowId);
                $('#update').val('update');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../../crud/read/view.php',
                    data: $('#modalFormUpdate').serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                    let parsedJson = JSON.parse(data);
                        alert(parsedJson.title);
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

if you want to read more about JSON.parse()
here's the link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

hope it might help :)